# Running out of memory on ai engine without changing batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am training a tensorflow ml model on google clouds AI engine.  I am loading my data into a tf.data.Dataset, and use a batch size of 10. I first try to train my model on one dataset, and it works fine. As I understand the model just trains on one batch at the time, so the amount of data in one batch should determine if I run out of memory of not. Is this right?

When I train on a larger dataset, I do run out of memory even though one batch is of the same size as with the smaller dataset. I don't understand how this could happen since it is the size of one batch that counts. Is my reasoning here wrong?

Comment: Hi Helga, have you check the memory utilization graph? Your code may leak memory slowly.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Actually I figured out that my problem was when loading the data into memory and not during training (as I though when asking this question)